# HMM for animal trajectories

Tags: bayesian, inference, hidden-markov-models

I am currently trying to fit a Hidden Markov Chain model to understand the trajectories of some animals which were followed through GLS (I've got coordinates and error). I would like to infer a behaviour state from the distance traveled each day and the associated turning angle.

I know I can use a Gamma distribution for the distance and a Von Mises one for the angles. I understand that HMM can be used without having true state observation (through the Viterbi algorithm) but I am lost in the order everything happens. If I understand well :

1. We set up the parameters priors
2. We build the transition matrix aka the matrix with the probabilities to switch from one state to another from t to t+1
3. We build the observation matrix (but I don't really understand how we can do this without knowing what the states really are...)
4. We compute the likelihood
5. We use the Viterbi algorithm to infer the states

I think that's the right order but the third step is kinda confusing in this inference process... (If it helps I am trying to do this using Nimble [I only have the distance compound and one individual to start with something more simple] :

```
hmm.traj <- nimbleCode({
  
  # Prior 
  ## Transition
  phi.S ~ dunif(0, 1)
  phi.NS ~ dunif(0, 1)
  
  ## Observation
  alpha.S ~ dunif(0.1, 10)  # Prior shape Gamma distribution (distance) : in-search
  beta.S ~ dunif(0.1, 10)   # Prior scale Gamma distribution (distance) : in-search
  alpha.NS ~ dunif(0.1, 10) # Prior shape Gamma distribution (distance) : in-transit
  beta.NS ~ dunif(0.1, 10)  # Prior scale Gamma distribution (distance) : in-transit
  
  # Initial state probability
  delta[1] <- 0 # Pr(in-search t = 1) = 0
  delta[2] <- 1 # Pr(in-transit t = 1) = 1
  
  # Transition matrix
  gamma[1,1] <- phi.S      # Pr(in-search t -> in-search t+1)
  gamma[1,2] <- 1 - phi.S  # Pr(in-search t -> in-transit t+1)
  gamma[2,1] <- 1 - phi.NS # Pr(in-transit t -> in-search t+1)
  gamma[2,2] <- phi.NS     # Pr(in-transit t -> in-transit t+1)
    
  # Observation matrix
  omega[1,1] <- alpha.S
  omega[1,2] <- beta.S
  omega[2,1] <- alpha.NS
  omega[2,2] <- beta.NS
  
  # Observation matrix for the initial state
  mean.S <- 15
  sd.S <- 5
  mean.NS <- 50
  sd.NS <- 20
  
  omega.prime[1,1] <- (mean.S / sd.S)^2
  omega.prime[1,2] <- mean.S / sd.S^2 
  omega.prime[2,1] <- (mean.NS / sd.NS)^2
  omega.prime[2,2] <- mean.NS / sd.NS^2 
    
  
  # Likelihood
  ## Iteration over individuals
  for (i in 1:N) {
    z[i, 1] ~ dcat(delta[1:2]) # t = 1
    y[i, 1] ~ dgamma(shape = omega.prime[z[i,1], 1],
                      rate = omega.prime[z[i,1], 2])
    
    ## Iteration over time
    for (t in 2:T) {
      z[i,t] ~ dcat(gamma[z[i,t-1], 1:2])
      y[i,t] ~ dgamma(shape = omega[z[i,t], 1],
                      rate = omega[z[i,t], 2])
    } # t
  } # i
  
})
```

In this code, I know the z is wrong because it should contain the states but I think if I understand the general process better, I should be able to code it in the proper way. This is my first hmm, so sorry if I misunderstood a few things...

Have a wonderful day !